# How to run raw mongoDB commands using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm able to change the mongodb's-sort-buffer-size using below command

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: <limit in bytes>})
```

but, how to run the same command using mongoose library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourModel.db.db.admin().command({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: <limit in bytes>}, function (err,res)
{
    console.log(res);
});
```

**Update:**

You can also do it without `YourModel`.

```
mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 268435456}, function (err,result)
{
    console.log(result);
});
```

Just make sure you do it after the connection has been established.

**Recommendation:**

While the above will work for you, if the query that needs this is a frequently used query, you should consider using indexing.