# How to set 'cursorTimeoutMillis' using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am using mongoose (4.13.10) in a nodeJs server to connect to a mongodb instance using

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/mydb')
```

I am using cursors to iterate over the records of my database and making multiple queries to the database which takes a lot of time and thus I am getting `Cursor not found` exceptions. I have found that these happen due to the idle timeout of cursors which matches my observations.

Now I don't want to flag `nocursortimeout` as true and instead set the timeout to some high value by which I am sure the long running queries will be done. But I am unable to find any documentation or guide how to set the the `cursorTimeoutMillis` server parameter.

How do I set this parameter? If possible I would like to set it for a particular cursor and not on the whole connection. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `cursorTimeoutMillis` option using mongodb-native-client, like :

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) => {
  // Use the admin database for the operation
  const adminDb = db.admin();

  // Set the cursor timeout millis option
  adminDb.command({
    setParameter: 1,
    cursorTimeoutMillis: <num>
  }, function(err, info) {
    // Close the connection
    db.close();
  });
});
```

---

From mongoose, like :

```
YourModel.db.db.admin().command({}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

---

To set it directly at the database run :

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=300000
```

---

**Docs**

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Admin.html#command

[How to run raw mongoDB commands using mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734733/how-to-run-raw-mongodb-commands-using-mongoose)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.cursorTimeoutMillis

Comment: `maxTime` sets the timeout while processing. I want to set the idle cursor timeout. Reason why I want to set the `cursorTimeoutMillis` instead.

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood correctly your question. I've performed an edit

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems like it would work but I am stuck trying to authenticate against the admin database. The user authenticating the initial connection has no perms in the admin data (obviously) and thus I am unable to `admin().command()`. I have also checked that the `setParameter` command has to be performed against admin db.

Comment: Maybe you could create an other user having the admin rights or gives admin right to your current user. Look at [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/). If you get any trouble with the rights, open a new question, you i'll answers really fast on that one :)

Comment: > and check this [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized), if you get `MongoDB - admin user not authorized` error !